# facebook fbml login-button not working with perms

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml

I recently ran into a problem when I upgraded to the new php and js sdk

before the login button below worked fine, and the dialog box popped up for a user to grant permission.

```
<fb:login-button perms="email,user_about_me,user_interests,user_location,publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access,publish_checkins">Connect Facebooks</fb:login-button>
```

Now the dialog won't pop up, but if I take out the "perms" and use this button

```
<fb:login-button">Connect Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

the dialog does pop up. any ideas?

Comment: I can't replicate this (in Google Chrome).  Is it affecting a particular browser?

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm using google chrome also. I'm upgrading to the new oauth 2.0, it was fine before i upgraded =/

Comment: Ah - then it appears that you're a victim of this bug, currently being triaged: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19733

Comment: That would be exactly it. Not much I can do until Facebook fixes the issue I guess right?

Comment: Added an answer with a workaround

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** The bug causing this issue was [resolved](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19733#c12), so your best option is to use `<fb:login-button>` still, but change "perms" to "scope" to match the latest API changes:

```
<fb:login-button
    scope="email, user_about_me, user_interests, user_location,
    publish_stream, read_stream, offline_access, publish_checkins">
    Connect Facebooks
</fb:login-button>
```

If you're still seeing issues after that or want an alternative login button style:
there's actually nothing very special about `<fb:login-button>`, it's just an easy way to render a login button, which is (mostly) a thing that calls `FB.login()` when clicked. You can make your own login button with just a little bit more work by doing something like:

```
<a id="fb_login_button" href="#" 
      onclick="FB.login(function(){ /* this is a callback function */ },
      {scope: 'email, user_about_me, user_interests, user_location,
       publish_stream, read_stream, offline_access, publish_checkins'});
       return false;">
    <img src="LOGIN_BUTTON_IMAGE.png" alt="Log In with Facebook">
</a>
```

Where the login button image is any image or text (you could even use a screenshot of the one rendered by `<fb:login-button>`).

*(note: inline `onclick` used here so this is library-independent, not implying it's a good practice to do so)*